# Why only does idle play from my animation script?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm making a custom animation script for a custom character on Roblox. The AI works fine but it will almost always only play idle animations even with humanoid events.

What should normally happen is when the monster is Idle the idle animation should play. When walking the walk animation should play. And when the AI attacks, the attack animation should play.

I've dried commenting out the idle animation part, but then no animations play at all.

Here's the code:

```
local myHuman = script.Parent.Humanoid
local walkAnim = myHuman:LoadAnimation(script.Parent.Walk)
local idleAnim = myHuman:LoadAnimation(script.Parent.Idle)
local jumpAnim = myHuman:LoadAnimation(script.Parent.Jump)

myHuman.Running:Connect(function(speed)
    if speed > 3 then
        walkAnim:Play()
    else
        walkAnim:Stop()
        idleAnim:Play()
    end
end)

myHuman.Jumping:Connect(function()
    jumpAnim:Play()
end)

myHuman.Died:Connect(function()
    for i,v in pairs(myHuman:GetPlayingAnimationTracks()) do
        v:Stop()
    end
end)
```

Comment: What are the animation's priorities? are they action and idle?

Comment: Walk's priority is Movement Idle's priority is Idle and Jump's is Movement aswell. Attack is Action and it doesn't even play.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a print instead of the animation and see what happens and tell me if it prints anything.

```
myHuman.Running:Connect(function(speed)
    if speed > 3 then
           print("walk")
       else
           print("start idle")
    end
end)
```

Edit:  https://devforum.roblox.com/t/getplayinganimationtracks-is-deprecated/1075650 I believe that you must do
`myHuman.Animator:getPlayingAnimationTracks()`

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that.
Edit: It only prints start idle 3 times.

Comment: Have you tried using myHuman.Animator:getPlayingAnimationTracks()?